# Map iteration race detector in golang map[string]float64

Tags: go

I have a map in golang myMap map[string]float64 which is pre-initialized. I'm trying to iterate over it and run coroutine functions on with keys

```
for k, v := range myMap {
  go func() {
    f(k,v)
  }()
}
```

But I'm getting a race detected using go run -race a.go in above which I'm not able to resolve.
I also tried the following but it still gives the same error.

```
for k, v := range myMap {
  go func(k string) { 
    f(k,v)
  }(k)
}
```

Comment: Create a [mre] showing the actual race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example the variable `v` from the range loop is still being accessed by multiple go routines at the same time causing the race condition.
Instead pass `v` into the function.

```
for k, v := range myMap {
    go func(k string, v float64) {
        f(k, v)
    }(k, v)
}
```

Or alternatively you could just call `f` using the `go` keyword.

```
for k, v := range myMap {
    go f(k, v)
}
```

Comment: I agree with using a named function. Way too many programmers overuse inline functions / lambdas in my opinion, when they ought to just call a function.